# how to manipulate with dom (datatable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, datatable

I am working on a project where, we are showing each year data summary to user, and in that summary they will see each years total data. (counted rows).

IMG : [data summary](https://screenshots.firefox.com/To6lx6CRokkfpY7w/localhost)

and when user click on "+" icon he will see the data of that year.

Suppose i click on 2013:

IMG: [data summery of the year 2013](https://screenshots.firefox.com/RJHrm8WVq3BFWbOW/localhost)

Now on how its working: when someone click on + icon,

```
function view_data(year)
{
$.ajax({
            url: "data_summary_year.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'&year='+year,
            success: function(response)
            {
                // console.log(response);
                 $('#text-inputs').removeClass('hidden');
                document.getElementById("show_year_data").innerHTML = response;
                document.getElementById("year_show").innerHTML = year;
            }
       });
}
```

and in data_summary_year.php

```
    <?php
require_once "../database/db.php";

     $year = $_POST['year'];

     $db_handle = new DBController();

    $db_handle->conn->set_charset("utf8");

    $data = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT `id`, `DocNo`, `DName` WHERE `RDate` = '$year'");


if(!empty($data))
{
         foreach($data as $k=>$v)
         {

                 echo "
                         <tr>

                            <th>".$data[$k]['id']."</th>

                            <th>".$data[$k]['dateofexecution']."</th>

                            <th>".$data[$k]['RDate']."</th>

                           //trying to show less data same like this one --"--

                            </tr>";

        }
}


?>
```

When i receive `response` from ajax success i just send that data to `<tbody>`.

You can view result in **data summary of the year 2013** image.

**My Issue:** when I search something in datatable its show nothing because datatable is working with dom and that data i send on `<tbody>` is not in dom.

**my search image:**  https://screenshots.firefox.com/q1pKZZ8o38YTOXZg/localhost

Now i can show result but user can't search anything; any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the plugin from datatables.net?  If so, you can tie into the [search event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/search) on the table, and write some JS to search the markup of the other table.  Since it's not one combined table, the plugin won't search both tables.

Is the other table using the same plugin?  You could potentially trigger that datatable to search the same way...